# Cannot process 'reportname.rdlc' because it is not an EDMX file

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, report, edmx

I've inherited a C# app which uses an .rdlc file.  I get an error (not a warning) in my error list:

> Cannot process 'reportTerminalStatus.rdlc' because it is not an EDMX
>   file.

but unlike normal code compilation errors it doesn't prevent the production of an executable file.   I don't want to ignore it, but is it safe too?

I've googled for information about the specific problem, but I'm not coming up with anything. I'm using VS2010 Ultimate on Windows 2008 server, and I've just run Windows Update so I have to assume I'm fully up to date.  Am I missing a component?  I've tried it on a VS2008 machine with the same results.

Comment: Hard to guess how you got from a report file to an entity framework file warning.

Answer (score 5):

This sometimes happens when build action is wrong for a file. In Visual Studio check properties for rdl. It might be set to EntityDeploy which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

according to

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Web_Services/Q_25956424.html

It has something to do with naming clash - specifically - you may have an entity (as in entity framework Entity) called

```
reportTerminalStatus
```

in the project, sharing the same path as the rdlc report.

Does changing the report name change anything ?

Comment: Sadly, this has made no difference.