# Cannot process 'StudentGrantsWF.xaml' because it is not an EDMX file

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow-foundation-4, edmx, workflow-activity

I am trying to add a new workflow activity but it is giving me this error:

> Cannot process 'StudentGrantsWF.xaml' because it is not an EDMX file.

I have two other activities, but they were added before this project was added to this solution that has four class library projects and three web applications inside it.

I am using Entity Framework 6.1.1.

[Edit] After changing the name the error disappeared but it appeared again when I tried referencing the project that has this activity in the web application project that has entity framework.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened that I was searching for the error and find this question [Cannot process 'reportname.rdlc' because it is not an EDMX file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396833/cannot-process-reportname-rdlc-because-it-is-not-an-edmx-file)

one of the answers pointed out that it might be a naming clash specifically if I have an entity that has a similiar name, though not exact name.

Changing the name worked for me but I had another problem as edited in the question! Yet I hope this solution also helps someone!